# How to process this matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

The original matrix is as follow:

```
Id: 0

Id: 1

group:  Book

Id: 2

group:  Book

Id: 3

group:  Music

Id: 4

group:  Book

Id: 5

Id:     6

group:  Book
```

In this matrix, `Id =0` and `Id=5` do not have their group, so there is no following row for its group.

Therefore, I hope to discard rows like "Id:   0"   and "Id:   5", the output new matrix as the following format:

```
Id   group


1    Book

2    Book

3    Music

4    Book

6    Book
```

I do not know how to do on Matlab...... Thanks for your help

Comment: what is the data type of your original "matrix"?

Comment: data type is Number(double)

Comment: that does not make much sense, how is the group info encoded? you might want to upload your original matrix or at least put up a screen shot

Comment: Just type the matrix name in Matlab (for a small case) and paste the output.